# Can we have state base routing in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

Can we have a state base routing in Aurelia JS like angular **ui router**
Currently I have routes like this 
root/<**userid**>/<**feature**>.
Now I am just trying to implement the same in following way 
root/<**userid**> and *feature should be pass as a parameter*.The problem is that 
Once the component is loaded in memory it is not getting updated on params change.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the lifecycle to be invoked any time the URL parameters change.

See "Reusing an Existing VM" at the link below.

http://aurelia.io/hub#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/7

"Since the VM's navigation life-cycle is called only once you may have problems recognizing that the user switched the route from Product A to Product B (see below). To work around this issue implement the method determineActivationStrategy in your VM and return hints for the router about what you'd like to happen."

In your view model write the following method:

```
determineActivationStrategy {
    return activationStrategy.invokeLifecycle;
}
```